# Line numbers in Spyder disappear

Tags: spyder

I write python on `Spyder` version `2.3.4`.

After reaching line 68, **the line numbers disappear** from my Spyder code window.
This even happens when opening a new file and just inserting newlines up to line 68. Deleting lines so that there are less than 68 makes the line numbers reappear.

Line 100 onwards show only the last digit, so it is some graphical bug that causes the right part of the the line number to disappear.

This blocks me from seeing the PEP8 remarks, and resetting spyder settings did not help.

I cannot provide screenshots, as the computer on which the bug occurs is not connected to the internet.

I did not see this bug documented anywhere in google. What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: What operating system do you have? Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I use Windows 7.

Comment: A couple of additional questions: How did you install Spyder? Do you have pep8 warning activated all the time?

Comment: I installed it through Anaconda. Disabling the pep8 warnings (as a particular effect of resetting all settings) did not help. Is it safe to uninstall and reinstall Spyder, meaning all scripts will survive?

Comment: Yes, it's safe to uninstall and reinstall Spyder, but I don't that will help. I've never seen this error on Windows, and if I can't reproduce it I can't fix it, sorry.